# adding mp3 sound to wikitude AR augmented reality, not playing

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, wikitude

i am unfamiliar with JavaScript, and wanted to add an mp3 file to play when the wikitude world starts, however it is not playing. there is no audio,

i used the tutorials on the wikitude website to add wikitude as part of an Android app.

documentation for class sound of wikitude sdk

http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/alr/Sound.html

here is the code selection for the audio

```
  streamingSound = new AR.Sound("assets/soundtest.mp3", {
                            onError : errorLoadingSound,
                            onFinishedPlaying : readyToPlay,
                            onLoaded : readyToPlay,
                    });

 streamingSound.load();
 streamingSound.play();
```

here is the full code for the file  multiplepois.js

```
 var World = {

  markerDrawable_idle: new AR.ImageResource("assets/lion.png"),

  // New: a second image resource which represents a selected marker
  markerDrawable_selected: new AR.ImageResource("assets/marker_selected.png"),

  // New: a array holding a reference to all marker objects
  markerList: [],

  init: function initFn() {

    AR.context.onLocationChanged = World.onLocationChanged;

    // New: a custom callback which will be invoked when the user taps on an empty  screen space
    AR.context.onScreenClick = World.onScreenClick;
},

  onLocationChanged: function onLocationChangedFn(latitude, longitude, altitude, accuracy) { 

    AR.context.onLocationChanged = null;


    streamingSound = new AR.Sound("assets/soundtest.mp3", {
                            onError : errorLoadingSound,
                            onFinishedPlaying : readyToPlay,
                            onLoaded : readyToPlay,
                    });

  streamingSound.load();
  streamingSound.play();


 }

    // New: Markers are now created using the new operator.
    //      The marker definition is in `marker.js`.
    //      Title, description and location are supplied in the json compatible format
    var poiData = {
        "latitude": 31.580,
        "longitude": 130.545,
        "altitude": altitude,
        "title": "Marker 1",
        "description": "forever office"
    };
    World.markerList.push(new Marker(poiData));

     poiData = {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude - 0.5,
        "altitude": altitude,
        "title": "Marker 4",
       "description": "West"
    };
   World.markerList.push(new Marker(poiData));
   },

    onScreenClick: function onScreenClickFn() {

    for (var i = World.markerList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (World.markerList[i].isSelected) {
            World.markerList[i].setDeselected(World.markerList[i]);
        }
     }
  }
};

World.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ADE (ade.js) included with the SDK to check for any js errors using a desktop browser. JS errors will be reported on Android in logcat as well. However depending on the phone this might be hard to spot.

Checking your code with the ADE in a desktop browser reveals that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: errorLoadingSound is not defined
```

If you just want to play the sound:

```
streamingSound = new AR.Sound("assets/soundtest.mp3");
streamingSound.play();
```

Disclaimer: I work for Wikitude